How to Retrieve Data Stream Status via API in Salesforce Data Cloud?
I am working with Salesforce Data Cloud and need to retrieve the status of Data Streams using an API. Does anyone know if there is an available approach or API endpoint to achieve this?
Any guidance or documentation references would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried to retrieve the Data Streams using Query API.
